# struct NSMutableString Warning

Tags: nsstring

Hi to all am used following line code in my xml parsing class it works but giving me warning as "**warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSMutableString** *'"

Can Anybody tell me about how to resolve this warning.

```
NSMutableString *currentElementValue = [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` returns immutable string object (NSString), if you want to get mutable NSMutableString you need to make extra step to create it:

```
NSMutableString *currentElementValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:
                      [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: Or here I declare "currentElementValue" as "NSString" that also solve warning